# Firebase messaging warning messages on service worker install process

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm using firebase for push web notifications, my file `firebase-messaging-ws.js` is something like this:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-messaging.js');

    
fetch('./firebase-data.json')
.then(r => r.json())
.then(fbData => {
    let app = firebase.initializeApp(fbData);    
    firebase.messaging(app);
    console.log('Firebase Service Worker loaded for projectId:', fbData.projectId);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error configuring firebase messaging: ', err)
});
```

I'm using a json file, `firebase-data.json` to load the firebase configuration data and It works, I can receive push notifications, however several log warnings appear in the console when I call to `firebase.messaging()`, If I use a local object (without fetch() command) then all works OK and there is no warning messages.

The log messages are like `Event handler of 'XXX' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.`:
[image]

Can I avoid the warning messages when I use an external file to load the firebase configuration data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically a service worker script requires synchronous execution, meaning you can't initialize Firebase Messaging within a promise.

Spitballing here, this is untested, but try this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const response = await fetch('./firebase-data.json');
const fbData = await response.json();

let app = firebase.initializeApp(fbData);    
firebase.messaging(app);
console.log('Firebase Service Worker loaded for projectId:', fbData.projectId);
```

Alternatively, if it doesn't like await outside of an async function, use JavaScript to export your config data and use importScripts to expose it to your service worker:

**firebase-data.js**

```
const fbData = {...};
```

**firebase-messaging-ws.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('./firebase-data.js');

let app = firebase.initializeApp(fbData);    
firebase.messaging(app);
console.log('Firebase Service Worker loaded for projectId:', fbData.projectId);
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, the `await` opton doesn't make any difference, however defining the  varaible `fbData`into a js file works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer explains, moving the `fbData` to a `js` file allow the variable to be used inside the Service Worker script.

Just for the record, I did all of this to share the Firebase data between the Service Worker scope and the Angular application scope, The `firebase-data.js` is something like this:

```js
const FIREBASE_DATA = {
    "apiKey": "***********",
    "authDomain": "***********.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://***********.firebaseio.com",
    "projectId": "***********",
    "storageBucket": "***********.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "***********",
    "appId": "1:***************"
}


if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = { ...FIREBASE_DATA }
}
```

With this implementation I can use `self.FIREBASE_DATA` inside the service worker file and I can also import the module in my angualr app, por instance mi `environment.ts` is something like:

```js
import FIREBASE_DATA from "../firebase-data";

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url_base: '/api',
  firebase: FIREBASE_DATA
};
```